# Chat simple con socket.io, ¿cómo lo ejecuto en mi hosting remoto?

Tags: javascript

estoy viendo un tutorial básico de un chat simple realizado con socket.io, pero veo que todos los ejemplos son ejecutados en el localhost, y yo quisiera correr el proyecto en mi hosting remoto. Pero no se que líneas debo modificar, suponiendo que mi página es: www.mipagina.com

index. JS

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

.JSON

```
{
"name": "socket-chat-example",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "my first socket.io app",
"dependencies": {
"express": "4.10.2",
"socket.io": "1.2.0"
}
```

}

index.html

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
    body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
    form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
    form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
    form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
    #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
    #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ¿Tu hosting soporta algún tipo de c-panel o conexiones ssh?

Comment: Si, es un hosting gratuito pero tiene un panel de control, solamente quiero adaptar el código a mi hosting remoto para probar el ejemplo, pero no se que lineas modificar...

Comment: Bueno, en ese caso simplemente deberías ejecutarlo como lo haces localmente, que me he de suponer sería algo así: `node index.js` y accederías a el por medio de *www.mipagina.com:3000*

Comment: Claro que debes cerciorarte primero que tu hosting soporte node, tengas los paquetes, instalados, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En caso tengas un servidor dedicado o un servidor que incluya Node.js, lo que tienes que hacer es un Proxy en Apache para redirigir tráfico hacia tu aplicación en un determinado puerto.

Podrías poner el chat en el puerto 9000 por ejemplo para lo cual necesitas hacer el Proxy a ese puerto. Para ésto debes editar el *site* por defecto dentro de */etc/apache2/sites-available* (por lo general llamado *default*). En éste ejemplo redireccionaremos `chat.tupaginaweb.com` a la aplicación Node.js en el puerto 9000.

> **Nota**: No olvides activar los módulos `proxy` y `proxy_http`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName chat.tupaginaweb.com
  ServerAlias www.chat.tupaginaweb.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/tuappnode/
  Options -Indexes

  ProxyRequests on
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

El *DocumentRoot* debe ser tu aplicación Node.js y debe estar ubicada dentro de */var/www*.