# Ejecutar node.js socket.io desde hosting web

Tags: nodejs, socket.io

Vengo trabajando con estos dos servicios desde consola, haciendo que el servidor inicie ejecutando los comandos por consola (nodemon servidor.js), todo lo que encuentro en la web es utilizando localhost, funciona perfecto no he tenido problemas, mi pregunta es, si yo deseo iniciar el servidor desde un hosting web, es decir ahora no quiero hacerlo mas de manera local con xampp sino desde un hosting. (lo cuál no puedo practicarlo porque no tengo un hosting, y los hosting gratuitos son muy limitados). ¿Como lo haría?.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Chat simple con socket.io, ¿cómo lo ejecuto en mi hosting remoto?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45642/chat-simple-con-socket-io-c%c3%b3mo-lo-ejecuto-en-mi-hosting-remoto)

Answer (score 1):

El problema es justo ese, que con un hosting gratuito vas a tener muy complicado poder hacerlo

Necesitas abrir puertos especificos, ejecutar tus programas desde un servidor con NodeJs instalado, etc...

Los hosting gratuitos suelen tener solo PHP instalado o a veces ni siquiera eso. Mirate algun VPS barato que es lo que necesitas para poder desplegar tu aplicacion